# How to register assembly in Net Framework 4.0

Tags: sql-server-2005, .net-4.0

I have an net assembly that was originally written in framework 1.1.
I have complied this with a framework 4.0 and need to put in the GAC
There is no Framework configuration tool (Administrative Tools/Microsoft .Net Framework n.n Configuration any longer.

How do I view/Manage Framewok 4.0 GAC assemblies.

I am using this assembly with Sql server 2005 'SP_OA....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Windows Explorer. Open Windows Explorer and go into the `assembly` folder inside your Windows folder. You should then see all the assemblies that are registered, if you want to add yours in, just drag and drop it in there.

Or if you prefer, you can locate the gacutil.exe and use that to do it (but it's not installed with the framework nowdays, only with the SDK I think).

Comment: There's also a command-line GACUtil.exe, and a setup project has the ability to drop the assembly into the GAC.

Comment: And just in case the comment looks a little funny, I was editing my answer just as Steven wrote that so his comment made perfect sense when he wrote it.